# django return nothing/to the exact same location after a user's action

Tags: python, django

I am doing a reddit-clone project and one of the feature is to do upvote/downvote. I want the user to be able to click on upvote/downvote right on the post-list.html page and show the updates and nothing else. I tried to return None but django doesn't allow it. I tried to return to the "/" but then django returns a webpage from the top.

In addition, I feel that my upvote/downvote takes a long time to update, which is strange, I am wondering if there is a way to speed it up.

Here is my base.html that has the upvote/downvote feature:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    <div class="post">
      <div class="vote">{% include "Reddit_app/vote-thumbnail.html" with el=post %}</div>
```

Here is the vote-thumbnail.html

```
<div class="voting_panel">
    <div class="vote-logo"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up
      {% if el|user_has_voted:user == 1 %} text-success {%else%} text-muted {% endif %}" href="{% url 'upvote-thumbnail' pk=el.pk %}"></a></div>
    <div class="score">{{ el.get_score }}</div>
    <div class="vote-logo"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down
      {% if el|user_has_voted:user == -1 %} text-success {%else%} text-muted {% endif %}"  href="{% url 'downvote-thumbnail' pk=el.pk %}"></a></div>
</div>
```

Here is my urls.py with the post-link

```
    path('content/<uuid:pk>/upvote-thumbnail/', views.vote_thumbnail, {'is_upvote': True}, name='upvote-thumbnail'),
    path('content/<uuid:pk>/downvote-thumbnail/', views.vote_thumbnail, {'is_upvote': False}, name='downvote-thumbnail')
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
```

Here is my views.py

```
def vote_thumbnail(request, pk, is_upvote):
    content_obj = Votable.get_object(pk)
    content_obj.toggle_vote(request.user, UserVote.UP_VOTE if is_upvote else UserVote.DOWN_VOTE)
    return redirect('/')  #what to return here?
```

Comment: What url path does post-list.html use. Can you share your url path for post-list.html. You can simple redirect to this url path by name of that url path: `redirect("post-list")`

Comment: This kind of thing is almost always done with an ajax request. And it's a good learning project to understand the basics of ajax. It's outside of the scope of stack overflow to give a full example of how to do that. But if you google "django ajax tutorial", you will find many examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To redirect to the previous URL, we can use `request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')` or use `redirect("post_list")`

```
def vote_thumbnail(request, pk, is_upvote):
    content_obj = Votable.get_object(pk)
    content_obj.toggle_vote(request.user, UserVote.UP_VOTE if is_upvote else UserVote.DOWN_VOTE)
    # redirect to the previous page
    return redirect("post_list") # or redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

You can add `id` attribute to your link `<a id={{ el.pk }}>` and then use **hash** in your url `href="{% url 'downvote-thumbnail' pk=el.pk %}#{{ el.pk }}"`:

```
<div class="vote-logo">
    <a id="{{ el.pk }}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down {% if el|user_has_voted:user == -1 %} text-success {% else %} text-muted {% endif %}" href="{% url 'downvote-thumbnail' pk=el.pk %}#{{ el.pk }}"></a>
</div>
```

The browser window will scroll itself (instantly) into such a position where the element with the ID is visible.

Comment: when I do request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'), it directs me back to the link of the vote.. which is a blank page

Comment: Are you using ajax?

Comment: @llu13701, try: `return redirect("post_list")`

Comment: if i do ```redirect("post_list")```, then it returns to the top of the page.. i would like it to return to the exact spot

Comment: @llu13701, You can add `id` attribute to your link `<a id={{ el.pk }}>` and then use **hash** in your url `href="{% url 'downvote-thumbnail' pk=el.pk %}#{{ el.pk }}"`. I updated my answer.